# How to link to another html page with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I am able to have another html page appear when clicking "register" but it is currently separate from the "register" button that I had originally created. The href sits right beside the button created and unable to find a way to make it sit inside the button. Is there another way to do this to have it work inside the button?

I've tried adding the  Register which works inside of the button that I created but it did not work, the button breaks

```
       <a class="btn" href="Register.html"> Register</a>
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
          id="registerLink"
         ></button>
```

Working on a "Log in" form. On the click of the register button the register form I had completed previously should appear. I am trying to get back 1 single button in my class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" button.

Comment: `<a href="Register.html" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"> Register</a>` try it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same classes to the link that you have added to the button and it should now look like a button instead of a link.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="Register.html" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"> Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two buttons. One of them doesn't have a closing tag. That's going to result in unpredictable behavior. I am not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: Good catch, I edited because that was from me trying to fix my issues. I am trying to have my "Register Button" on click, open to a registration form that I created. I currently have a text link that says "Register" above the gray button I created. The text link works the way I would like it to, but I would like to make my gray button the link it instead. Hope that clarifys

Comment: You can wrap any element, including your button in the <a> tag. This would make it a link. The text inside the button will inherit the link, as well. If you don't want the inside text to display blue, you can use the CSS property "text-decoration: none".